# SEO friendly link in codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

First of all sorry if the question has been already posted, but I didn't got any ans ...

My question is ..
Developing a app in codeigniter.

I am making a link like this

```
echo site_url('controller_name/book/'.$variable_name);
```

Which will display the details of a book . I would likes to make a URL like follows

```
http://www.sitename/book/book_name ( name of the book  )
```

please help me how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at [url_title()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html).

You can use this to set a SEO friendly URL. If you want underscores, don't forget to pass the second parameter.

```
$url_title = url_title($title, 'underscore');
```

Comment: Just an update, taken from [**url_title**](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/url_helper.html#url_title): _Old usage of ‘dash’ and ‘underscore’ as the second parameter is DEPRECATED._ -